# Rendering mess? Must I do a clean install or is this a feature?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

In the 3D view is a red cartoon fox but rendering using blender render, cycles render, I get this mess.
Why is it doing this?
How do I fix it?

v2.78a

[image]

Comment: Looks like your node tree is messed up. Can you post a picture?

Comment: No trees, no nodes, nothing.

Comment: Can you [post a `.blend` file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), then?

Comment: As I kept saving, save 7 rendered as it should save 8 on = mess. So either I hit a setting then or it's corrupt.

Comment: Please post a `.blend` file with the link I provided above.

Comment: I try to add the monkey head but it doesn't even render but I paste it in a new file is renders perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Select the entire character and all you want to keep hit ctrl+C to copy open a new Blender ctrl+V to paste. This will solve corrupt files most of the time.